# Gmail API: Is there a way to get RFC822 message id's when doing messages.list with a query?

Tags: gmail-api

From what I can tell there's no documented way to get RFC822 message id's when listing messages with a query.
It would be beneficial for us in avoiding fetching multiple times the same email from different inboxes...
Any insights?

Answer (score 1):

You can only get the `messageId` and `threadId` of messages when listing them, and a `resultSizeEstimate` of the entire query.

You have to list the messages and then get them in order to read the `Message-ID`-header.

Instead of listing `X` messages and doing `X` separate GET-requests for the messages, you can use [batch requests](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch) to only make 2 requests in total for each page.